# Any "upright freezers" that have a water/ice dispenser?

Tags: appliances

I'm trying to pick out kitchen appliances for a new kitchen.  We like the idea of having a "freezerless refrigerator" side by side with an "upright freezer" so that it has the appearance of a massive refrigerator but it's actually 2 separate units.

The only issue is I can't seem to find any upright freezers that have a water/ice dispenser.

I'm hoping someone on here is more knowledgeable on kitchen appliances and can tell me if such a product exists.

Comment: If you separate freezer and fridge, the best you can do may be ice dispenser in the former and cold water via the latter... though I haven't seen that either.

Answer (score 1):

They exist but I have only seen them for very high-end application.  [Here](http://www.thermador.com/refrigeration/freezer-columns/t24id800rp-24-inch-freezer-column-with-external-ice-and-water-dispenser) is an example.  I bought one for a house I was redoing a few years ago but have to say it is a little out of my price range.  Most of the models are made to take custom front panels (match cabinets).

Comment: "Request pricing" yikes, how much was that thing?

Comment: @Mazura - I helped flip a home - 3 investors - that was sold for 1.35 million bought for 550K.  It was a gut job that we put 400K into - doing a lot of work ourselves.  LOTS of items we bought were call for pricing... Guess the wealthy just buy.  But we put in this type of freezer - 36 inch model and Viking fridge that seemed to be 10 feet wide.  Those two things could by me transportation.